# Create and save new list item with Javascript and HTML 5

Tags: javascript, html, html-lists, local-storage

I have the following code.

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>

<html>

<head>

<script type="text/javascript">
function addChildElements()
{
var newdiv=document.createElement("li");
var newtext=document.createTextNode("test");
newdiv.appendChild(newtext); 
document.getElementById("scribble").appendChild(newdiv); 
}
</script>

<script>
  function storeUserScribble(id) {
    var scribble = document.getElementById('scribble').children;
    localStorage.setItem('userScribble',scribble);
  }

  function getUserScribble() {
    if ( localStorage.getItem('userScribble')) {
      var scribble = localStorage.getItem('userScribble');
    }
    else {
      var newdiv=document.createElement("li");
      var newtext=document.createTextNode("test");
      newdiv.appendChild(newtext); 
      document.getElementById("scribble").appendChild(newdiv); 
    }
    document.getElementById('scribble').children = scribble;
  }

  function clearLocal() {
    clear: localStorage.clear(); 
    return false;
  }
</script>

</head>

<body>

<ol id="scribble" contenteditable="false" onclick="storeUserScribble(this.id);">

</ol>

<input type="button" value="Add Child Element" onclick="addChildElements(); storeUserScribble(document.getElementById('scribble').id);"/>

</body>
</html>
```

Which is meant to save the list items as they are created, but i'm completely at a loss. This code doesn't work. I know it probably has something to do with:

```
var scribble = document.getElementById('scribble').children;
```

or

```
onclick="addChildElements(); storeUserScribble(document.getElementById('scribble').id);"
```

But that is about where my JS knowledge stops.

Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: what do you mean by `save the list items as they are created`?

Comment: I've just tried your code here http://jsfiddle.net/BRyVL/1/. And it seems to be working

Comment: It should save the list items you've added with local storage